# PDO my sql insert on how to insert only number characters

Tags: php, pdo

Hello I am using the following method to insert data into mysql with PDO,

```
if( isset( $data['passport'] ) ) $this->passport = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['passport'] ) );

$stmt->bindValue( "passport", $this->passport, PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

how I can get a result where only will be inserter numbers, and any special characters and letters will be removed including characters like - and +

any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: The other answer is way better, as you should verify, not silently truncate the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$this->passport = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $this->passport);

$stmt->bindValue( "passport", $this->passport, PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

Regular expression `/[^0-9]/` allows to catch all non-digit characters in supplied string. To remove them just replace them with empty string, i.e. `''`.

---

**UPDv1:** I would also suggest to notify user, if supplied data is incorrect, according to storage stucture. *Please, consider validation possibilities.*

```
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $this->passport)){
    echo 'Invalid data';
    // prevent database submition
}
```

Comment: *Why downvote here?* Please, be constructive while downvoting: leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of **`ctype_digit`** to check for only numbers.

Something like

```
if(ctype_digit($data['passport'])) //if only numbers
{
echo "Valid";
}
```